# How to set a default date on a Jekyll site?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want the date values of all pages to default to [`site.time`](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/variables/#site-variables) if no date is provided in the filename or front matter. Using `{{ site.time }}` in an html file (such as a layout) works but when I set it either in the front matter of the document, or in the defaults I get this error:

```
Invalid date 'site.time': An invalid date format was found in a front-matter default set: {"scope"=>{"path"=>""}, "values"=>{"date"=>"site.time"}} (Jekyll::Errors::InvalidDateError)
```

Here's my code in `_config.yml`:

```yaml
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: ""
    values:
      date: "{{ site.time }}"
      # OR
      date: site.time
      # OR
      date: "{{ site.time | date: '%d %b %Y' }}"
      # OR
      date: "now"
      # OR
      date: "{{ 'now' }}"
```

Is this possible? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: I could do something like this:

```html
{% if page.date %}
<div>Document date: {{ page.date }}</div>
{% else %}
<div>Document date: {{ site.time }}</div>
{% endif %}
```

But I'd have to do this for every single time and I'd rather just use `page.date` with the defaults as designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_config.yml` file is a static configuration file, you can't (easily) put the code that will be evaluated there.

The most viable approach is having a check if the variable is there and fallback to default one.
You can use shorter form with liquid `default` filter:

```html
<div>Document date: {{ page.publication_date | default: site.time }}</div>
```

Also, I'd recommend avoiding variable name `date` as it's already defined by Jekyll and used to generate url path for posts.

Comment: Thanks this is the method I ended up going with